# Dynamic id generate in java script with php laravel framework

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I have a problem on JavaScript id.In my code zooming working only the first image but its not work for another images.  HTML & PHP Laravel code:

[image]

JavaScript Code: how can i dynamic #click_image id?

[image]

Comment: Just bind some unique content with `click_image` id to make it dynamic. For ex:- `id="click_image_{{$item2->title}}"`

Comment: Sorry, it not work.

Comment: Pass a parameter in `myFunction({{$item2->title}})` and within that function you can access the current clicked image's id like `$('#click_image_'+param)`

Comment: solved my problem, the problem is id. actually here collection of elements, so replace the id with class.That's it. Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using class instead?

```
<img class="click_image " data-zoom-image="">
```

then on your js

```
 $(".click_image").data('data-zoom-image').elevateZoom({
     responsive : true,
     scroll : true
 });
```

You'll end up in a very messy javascript if you insist to bind it with ID like this.

```
@foreach($experiencezone as $key => $item )
......
<img id="click_image_{{ $key }}" data-zoom-image=""> 
......
@endforeach
// or if you have id on your collection
@foreach($experiencezone as $item )
......
<img id="click_image_{{ $item->any_id }}" data-zoom-image=""> 
......
@endforeach
```

and on your js

```
<script>
@foreach($experiencezone as $key => $item )
$("#click_image_{{ $key }}").data('data-zoom-image').elevateZoom({
     responsive : true,
     scroll : true
});
@endforeach
</script>
// or if you have id on your collection
<script>
@foreach($experiencezone as $item )
$("#click_image_{{ $item->your_id }}").data('data-zoom-image').elevateZoom({
     responsive : true,
     scroll : true
});
@endforeach
</script>
```

Comment: You can't do that. Zoom the image which is clicked not all. So your idea of using by `class` wont be useful in this case..

Comment: @YashParekh I think he used my idea of using class ( Read the comments on the post ).  Can you remove my downvote hehe? :D

Comment: @Romnick. This is my idea. i don't see your answer. its all about id and class.Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: @ArinaAfrinMitu no problem. As long as you solve your problems.

Comment: Thank you so much.@Romnick Susa